# Вывод опций из multiple select в отдельные php переменные

Tags: php

На html странице есть multiple select список, например

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="multi[]" multiple>
        <option value="Арбуз">Арбуз</option>
        <option value="Дыня">Дыня</option>
        <option value="Груша">Груша</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Вот мы взяли данные:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach ($_POST['multi'] as $selectedOption)
  echo $selectedOption.",";
}  
?>
```

Например, я выбрал все 3 (их может быть сколько угодно) опции, как их все вывести в отдельные переменные? Например multi(1), multi(2), multi(3).

Comment: В этом нет ни малейшего смысла. почему ты решил, что тебе это надо?

Comment: Можно я не буду доказывать что мой вопрос важен и нужен, хотя бы лично для меня?

Comment: Можно, но желательно все же пояснить свой вопрос. На досуге почитай [вот этот анекдот](http://www.anekdot.ru/id/-112721037/). Там чувак тоже считал что он умнее всех и не должен никому ничего доказывать.а проблема в итоге может быть просто в неверной терминологии

Comment: Но ведь программирование - это не операция, можно все откатить назад. Ну люди же как-то хранят данные из множественного select'а. Предположим, что в одной переменной. А как мне достать 1 опцию из этой самой переменной, как с ним работать? Например, я у меня есть дыня, арбуз , груша. Я хочу достать арбуз и вывести его на экран

Comment: Так и вывести, `echo $_POST['multi'][0];`. Как я и предполагал, никакой отдельной переменной для этого не требуется.